# Using code to write a function that calculates values for Projectile motion

Tags: python

I have an assignment that asks me to use some given code to write a function which calculates the angle needed to hit a target 10 metres away.

here is the given code:

```
from visual import *
from visual.graph import * # For the graphing functions 
#Create a graph display window (gdisplay) 

win = gdisplay(xtitle="Distance [m]", ytitle="Height [m]") 
#And a curve on this display 

poscurve = gcurve(gdisplay=win, color=color.cyan) 
#Target position (10 meters away) 

target_pos = vector(10,0,0) 
#Set the starting angle (in degrees) 

angle = 45 
#Set the magnitude of the starting velocity (in m/s) 

v0 = 12.0 
#Gravity vector (m/s**2) 

g = vector(0, -9.8, 0) 
#Create a vector for the projectile's velocity 

velocity = v0 * vector(cos(anglepi/180), sin(anglepi/180), 0) 
#and the position 

position = vector(0,0,0) 
dt = 0.01 # Time step 
#Start loop. Each time taking a small step in time 

while (position.y > 0) or (velocity.y > 0): # Change in position # dx =          (dx/dt) * dt dx = velocity * dt 
# Change in velocity 
# dv = (dv/dt) * dt 
dv = g * dt 

# Update the position and velocity 
position = position + dx 
velocity = velocity + dv 

# Plot the current position 
poscurve.plot(pos=position) 
#When loop finishes, velocity.y must be < 0, and position.y < 0 

print "Landed at X position: ", position.x print "X distance to target: ",     position.x - target_pos.x
```

How would I now write a function to calculate the required value? I have no idea where to start, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: SO users will probably not write your code but answer questions you formulate clearly.  If your question does not show enough knowledge it will be regarded off-topic here.

Comment: Looks like you are trying some numeric integration / motion simulation.  You will need a loop for this and vector computations in 2D at least.  Do this in your code, then maybe clear questions arise you can ask here.  Make sure to show us your code then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use maths to work out an equation for the result.

This works out as:

```
 range = 2v^2/g *cos(a)sin(a)

where v=initial velocity
a=angle
g=gravitational acceleration
```

You can use this python script to find the answer:

```
from math import cos
from math import sin
from math import radians
from math import fabs

a=0 # angle in degrees
target=10  # How far you want it to go in m
v=12 # initial velocity in m/s
g=9.81 #gravitational acceleration m/s/s

best_angle=None
nearest_answer=None

while a<45: # we only need to check up to 45 degrees
    r = 2*v*v/g*cos(radians(a))*sin(radians(a))
    if not nearest_answer or fabs(r-target)<fabs(nearest_answer-target):
        nearest_answer = r
        best_angle = a
    print("{0} -> {1}".format(a,r))
    a+=.1 # try increasing the angle a bit. The lower this is the more accurate the answer will be

print("Best angle={}".format(best_angle))
```